# I have written a module in js which handles the drag of HTML elements on a page but it does not work on Android

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop

The drag handler module does not work on Android.
It works on IOS and Windows.

Expecting to work on Android phones, just like on IOS or Windows.

How it should work on mobile: long tap to an element, drag the element over an other, release tap.

It works exactly like that on other OSes. Other module is calling the `init()` method every time it wants to reinit the drag handler.

**Here is the module's code:**

```js
import * as devices from "./devices.js"

var items = [];
var dragSrcEl = null;

var init = function(){
    items = document.querySelectorAll('.expander');
    items.forEach(function (item) {
        removeListeners(item);
        addListeners(item);
    });
}

var removeListeners = function (item) {
    item.removeEventListener('dragstart',   handleDragStart);
    item.removeEventListener('dragend',     handleDragEnd);
    item.removeEventListener('dragover',    handleDragOver);
    item.removeEventListener('dragenter',   handleDragEnter);
    item.removeEventListener('dragleave',   handleDragLeave);
    item.removeEventListener('drop',        handleDrop);
}

var addListeners = function (item) {
    item.addEventListener('dragstart',  handleDragStart);
    item.addEventListener('dragend',    handleDragEnd);
    item.addEventListener('dragover',   handleDragOver);
    item.addEventListener('dragenter',  handleDragEnter);
    item.addEventListener('dragleave',  handleDragLeave);
    item.addEventListener('drop',       handleDrop);
}

var handleDragStart = function(e) {
    this.style.opacity = '0.4';
}

var handleDragEnd = function(e) {
    this.style.opacity = '1';
}

var handleDragStart = function(e) {
    this.style.opacity = '0.4';
    dragSrcEl = this;

    e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
    e.dataTransfer.setData('text/html', this.innerHTML);
}

var handleDragEnd = function(e) {
    this.style.opacity = '1';
    items.forEach(function (item) {
        item.classList.remove('over');
    });
}

var handleDragOver = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
}

var handleDragEnter = function(e) {
    this.classList.add('over');
}

var handleDragLeave = function(e) {
    this.classList.remove('over');
}

var handleDrop = function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation(); // stops the browser from redirecting.
   
    if (dragSrcEl !== this) {
        dragSrcEl.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
        this.innerHTML = e.dataTransfer.getData('text/html');
        devices.reorderByDom();
    }

    return false;
}

export{init}
```

*Tested on chrome,firefox and edge in Android.*

Comment: I suspect you really want to be talking about OS/ ***Browser*** combinations rather than just operating systems.

Comment: Tested on chrome,firefox and edge in Android.

Comment: Did you try adding the touch event?

Comment: I did not try to replace the drag events with touch events.